# How to create a thread-safe pool of objects?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, thread-safety

In my server application (written in C#), I need to create a pool of same type of objects. I pull an object from pool when I need, and it goes back to pool when it is no longer needed. Mechanism needs to be thread safe since different threads will be asking and submitting these objects. I understand that frequently locking something to make thread-safe has an adverse effect on application performance. Can you suggest a design by which I can even avoid explicit locks?

Please can you suggest the way I can accomplish above? Ability to resize the pool (create additional if running short of objects) would be a great add-on.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do NOT attempt to avoid explicit locks until you have EVIDENCE that locks are the #1 cause of UNACCEPTABLE performance. Locks are the vast majority of the time incredibly fast, and if your locks are slow then odds are good you have a deep design problem in your application. Remember, locks are only slow *under contention*, and if you have a lot of contention, *you're probably doing something wrong.*

Answer (score 2):

This post will be of interest:

[ObjectPool<T> or similar for .NET already in a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698738/objectpoolt-or-similar-for-net-already-in-a-library)

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ObjectPooling.aspx) on CodeProject. I only had to make a minor tweak to how `WeakReference`s are stored, but other than that, it's running in production with no problems at all.