# Is there a name for this design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, nomenclature

There's a specific snippet of code that I often use for recycling objects in a list based on a data provider. I thought of making a class to run through the snippet, using a given class to handle each step. This problem is... I don't know what to name it. Does a design pattern exist that describes this reusing of snippets?

```
package
{
    public class RecycleOperationRunner implements IRecycleOperationRunner
    {
        public function RecycleOperationRunner()
        {

        }

        public function run(operation:IRecycleOperation):void
        {
            const m:int = Math.max(numObjects, numDataItems);

            for (var i:int = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                if (i < numDataItems)
                {
                    if (i < numObjects)
                    {
                        operation.reuseItem(i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        operation.createItem(i);
                    }

                    operation.setupItem(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    operation.removeItem(i);
                }
            }

            operation.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like what you have could be described as a "pool".  As in "[thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)" or "[connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)."

- [Pool (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool)
- [Object pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern)

It seems to deviate slightly in that typically you request a resource from a pool, and if all the resources are currently being used (leased) then you *block* until one becomes available.  In your example, you create one.  So you have a pool that automatically grows in size to be non-blocking.

Comment: Or in general, a *resource pool*.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks, I added a more general Wikipedia article.  One for exactly "resource pool" doesn't exist but that is a good generic name.

Comment: The pooling aspect is just an example of the concept. I think this is similar to the Command Pattern, but with configurable callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Here Martin Fowler describes a Pooling pattern and methods to the situation when all resources are in use and client requests a new one:
http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ResourcePool.html

Also see this discussion on implementation:
[C# Object Pooling Pattern implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510975/c-sharp-object-pooling-pattern-implementation)