# Equivalent of Twitter Thrift API for .NET

Tags: .net, twitter, load-balancing, rpc, thrift

If you program thrift based server-to-server calls, Twitter offers a very good api - com.twitter.common.thrift - which offers supporting multiple thrift servers, load balancing and some other good things.
Does anyone know if there's an equivalent for .NET?
I'm primarily interested in multi remote server support and load balancing, which I mentioned above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finally figured it out.
I had to adapt the code from this article and it gave me what I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510975/c-sharp-object-pooling-pattern-implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there're no equivalents. I had to develop on my own:
https://github.com/vyakhir/pooling