# How to cache COM Object to not create/dispose it for each request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, asp.net-web-api2

I have an `asp.net web-api2` application which is using `COM object` for interacting with data.
I have an `Engine` object that is working with it. Like this:

```
public class PVXEngine : IDisposable
{
    protected DispatchObject _pvxObject;
    public PVXEngine()
    {
       _pvxObject = new DispatchObject("ProvideX.Script");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       _pvxObject.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I don't want to recreate this object for every request.  How can i store my `PVXEngine` in my Application Context to not recreate it. ( I guess it will be disposed when Application Pool Recyles. )

Also if it is possible, refer me documentation where I can read about caching objects in Application Pool.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `PVXEngine` a class variable.  This **assumes** that the object is thread safe.

```
 public class PVXEngine : IDisposable
 {
     static protected DispatchObject _pvxObject = new DispatchObject("ProvideX.Script");
 }
```

If the object is not thread safe then I suggest using a resource pool as specified in [C# Object Pooling Pattern implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510975/c-sharp-object-pooling-pattern-implementation).

Comment: Thank You, Where I can find documentation to understand how static objects are stored in Application Pool ? Or am I wrong ?

Comment: A static object is only created once for the entire process.  More info can be found in the C# spec.