# Utilization of ArrayPool

Tags: c#, .net-core

I understand that the `ArrayPool` class was implemented to pool arrays only.

Can I use the `ArrayPool` implementation to pool objects (not arrays)? I don't see why not, except that it is a bit weird that it might return an array larger than what I requested.

I was thinking about something like this:

```cs
public class Worker
{
    ArrayPool<Channel> channels;

    public Worker() 
    {
        channels = ArrayPool<Channel>.Shared;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteSomething(string message)
    {
        // It gets a bit weird here...
        var rentedChannels = channels.Rent(1);
        await rentedChannels[0].DoWork();
        channels.Return(rentedChannels);
    }
}
```

For convenience, [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/8ef62ac01ea9363645668eb17f7464112f049b1a/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Buffers/ArrayPool.cs) is the link to the implementation of `ArrayPool<T>`.

Comment: `ArrayPool` is an abstract class. Your sample code wouldn't compile. You implement it however you want.

Comment: Like @DanielMann, you did not implement it correctly. Also, for objects, you need to use a different type. See the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510975/c-sharp-object-pooling-pattern-implementation

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are looking for is perhaps the `ObjectPool<T>`

See example
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/objectpool?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Hope it helps!